# delphi android black screen (unable to connect to database)

Tags: delphi

First time I tried on Delphi 10 (Seattle) to compile an android application and got an disappointment. Its a small test application using sqlite database. Database has only one table with few records (created just for testing purposes).

I link everything right (using firedac components) and in Delphi IDE my data shows. It also compiles without an error. The application also shows on my phone (HTC M8) but right after the splash screen, the screen goes black. Nothing !

If I disconnect the FDConnection and compile then the screen shows OK on the phone (without any data ofcourse). Then I tried this way :added a button on the form which I used to open the connection and the table manually but(when run) got a firedac error (unable to open database file).

What am I missing here ? Why cant the application open the database? Is there something else I must do ? Maybe trivial but I never did an android application before.

Comment: Did you specify the correct path to the database on the phone?

Comment: Did you look at the mobile sample for FireDAC/SQLite (in C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Mobile Snippets\FireDACSQLite)?

Comment: @uwe - not sure what you mean by specifying on the phone ? The connection is defined in the FDConnection property. Ken, I saw the example but still cant figure out what is the difference. The database connection points to a database which is not found on my disk.

Comment: In the example Ken mentioned the database is mapped to : C:\tempprojects\tasks.s3db . However, I cant find this database. The one I cant find opens and the one that is actually there, does not. Funny ...

Comment: You're not reading it. In the example I mentioned, the DB is created when the app is run (on the C: drive when running as a desktop app, in the proper location on the device when running on Android) in code. It's in the **Mobile Snippets** location for a reason (because it runs on a mobile device). Look harder. :-)

Comment: @Ken I get that... I was only wondering why the app wont connect to my local DB and giving me black screen. So unless I am missing the point, connecting to your local DB using android is not possible (correct me if I am wrong). The mentioned example was creating the DB on the fly which is not what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mobile app cannot find the database in the phone's storage. You need to create one if it does not exist. This must be done before you can connecting to the database. Basically assign the database parameter to the FDConnection in the BeforeConnect event. also ensure that **FDConnection's OpenMode = **CreateUTF8****

```
procedure TMainDataModule.FDConnection1BeforeConnect(Sender: TObject);
begin
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
  FDConnection1.Params.Values['Database'] := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'mydatabase.sdb');
{$ENDIF}
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

After googling for some time I found the information here
[mobile tutorial](http://docwiki.appmethod.com/appmethod/1.13/topics/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_FireDAC_and_SQLite_%28iOS_and_Android%29)
 that :

> "The database file is not available on your mobile device unless you
>   copy it to the mobile device or create it on the fly."

So basically, I can not connect to my existing database on the PC from my phone.